# snakemake: access workdir from inside log_handler script

Tags: logging, snakemake, workdir

I am trying to create a custom `log_handler` script that can save the workflow´s log as a JSON file inside `{workdir}/logs`. For that I need to know what is the current `workdir` but I cannot seem to access is from inside the script. Does anyone know how to access `workdir` from inside a `log_handler` script?

I have also tried using `Path.cwd()` from inside the script, but it did not work.

EDIT: to clarify this a bit more, `snakemake` allows to specify a `--log-handler-script`. According to the documentation:

```
Provide a custom script containing a function ‘def log_handler(msg):’. Snakemake will call this function for every logging output (given as a dictionary msg) allowing to e.g. send notifications in the form of e.g. slack messages or emails.
```

I am trying to write such a script (based on [this](https://gist.github.com/tsibley/9cd44b6c4f1ad5bc437fb4be60459d5b)) that parses the log messages and saves them in a file, ideally, inside the `workdir`. But for that, the script needs to be able to know the current workdir.

thanks,

Comment: Maybe it's me being thick but without an example I cannot understand what you are trying to do... Can you post an example of what the log_handler script should do (is this python, bash, or else?) and how you want to integrate it in the Snakefile?

Comment: Would `workflow.basedir` do the trick?

Comment: Already tried, and I get:

`AttributeError: module 'snakemake.workflow' has no attribute 'basedir'`

or

`NameError: name 'workflow' is not defined`